# Solving sum of exponentials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, summation

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$, how can $-e^{-x}+e^{x}=a$ be solved?
I have already tried to use the sum of exponential formula.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equation is equivalent to
$$\sinh(x)=\frac a2\iff x=\operatorname{argsinh}\left(\frac a2\right)$$

Or if you want let $X=e^x$ and solve the quadratic equation

$$-1+X^2=aX$$

Answer (score 7):

Well, I think this will work:  if $x \in \Bbb R$ satisfies

$-e^{-x} + e^x = a, \tag{1}$

then we can multiply through by $e^x$ to obtain

$-1 + e^{2x} = ae^x, \tag{2}$

and if we set $y = e^x$, then $y^2 = e^{2x}$, so (2) becomes

$-1 + y^2 = ay, \tag{3}$

or

$y^2 - ay -1 = 0. \tag{4}$.

We solve (4) *via* the quadratic formula:

$y = \dfrac{1}{2}(a \pm \sqrt{a^2 + 4}), \tag{5}$

and see that not only is the discriminant $a^2 + 4 > 0$, but in addition $\vert a^2 + 4 \vert > \vert a \vert^2$, which shows that exactly *one* root of (4) is positive, *always*, that root being

$y = \dfrac{1}{2}(a+ \sqrt{a^2 + 4}). \tag{6}$

Setting $x = \ln y$ with $y$ given by (6) does the trick, as may easily be checked by some simple algebraic maneuvers.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: It is always a pleasure to me to read your last words. They are so true ! Cheers.

Comment: @Claude Leibovivi:  indeed!  And thanks!

Comment: @1950RobertLewis very nice.

Comment: @kaka:  muchas gracias!

Comment: The simpler the better. Thanks.